# Limit of an autonomous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

Given the differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=y(y-1)(y-3)$$
I found $y=1$ is a stable point while $y=0$ and $y=3$ are unstable. However, I have to evaluale
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)$$
without solving the equation and given the initial condition $y(0)=2$.

Since $y=1$ is stable and $y=2$ is "near" of $y=1$, this let me conclude
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}y(t)=1?$$

And if there were another stable point, for example, $y=4$, the answer of the limit would still be $1$ because $y=2$ is close to it instead of $y=4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the sign of $\frac{dy}{dt}$. Observe that
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = y(y-1)(y-3) < 0 \quad \forall \, y \in (1,3).$$
It therefore converges towards $y = 1$ for $y(0) \in (1,3)$.